# How to hide the label whenever I select the spinner value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

1. {Actually whenever i click on the spinner value (official) label is
   created,at that time i click on the another spinner value "Normal"
   created label is hiding. this scenario working fine, But Coming To my
   2nd scenario -- whenever i click on the spinner value (Normal) first
   time,it showing an error}

   import kivy
   kivy.require('1.10.0')
   from kivy.core.window import Window
   from kivy.app import App
   from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
   from kivy.uix.label import Label
   from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
   from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
   from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

   Window.size = (500, 400)
   Window.clearcolor = (0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2)

   def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
       print('Selected Process', spinner, 'have text', text)

   class LRefConfigAutomation(App):
       config = None

   ```
   def build_config(self, config):
       config.setdefaults('LefConfigWindowSection', {
           'PartInputLabel': 'Please Enter your Part No',
           'TypeOfProcessLabel': 'Select Type Of Process',
           'NormalFolderName': 'Enter Normal Folder Name',

       })
       self.config = config

   def build(self):
       config = self.config
       root = FloatLayout()
       lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'PartInputLabel')
       self.label01 = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .90}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0), halign="left",
                            valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
       self.label01.bind(size=self.label01.setter('text_size'))
       self.label01.font_size = '14.5dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
       root.add_widget(self.label01)
       with self.label01.canvas:
           Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
           Rectangle(pos=self.label01.pos, size=self.label01.size)
       self.txtKemNo = TextInput(pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .90}, size_hint=(None, None),
                                 font_name="Georgia", size=(100, 30), multiline=False, hint_text="Part Number")
       root.add_widget(self.txtKemNo)
       lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'TypeOfProcessLabel')
       self.label02 = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .75}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0), halign="left",
                            valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
       self.label02.bind(size=self.label02.setter('text_size'))
       self.label02.font_size = '14.5dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
       root.add_widget(self.label02)
       with self.label02.canvas:
           Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
           Rectangle(pos=self.label02.pos, size=self.label02.size)
       self.requestsspinner = Spinner(
           # default value shown
           text='Select Process',
           # available values will be binded to the combo
           values=("Normal", "Official"),
           # just for positioning in our example
           size_hint=(None, None),
           size=(110, 20),
           pos_hint={'center_x': .66, 'center_y': .75}, font_name='Georgia')
       self.requestsspinner.font_size = '14.5dp'
       self.requestsspinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)
       self.requestsspinner.bind(text=self.CreateLable)
       root.add_widget(self.requestsspinner)

       return root

   def CreateLable(self, spinner, text):
       config = self.config
       if text == "Official":
           lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'NormalFolderName')
           self.label03 = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),
                                halign="left", valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
           self.label03.bind(size=self.label03.setter('text_size'))
           self.label03.font_size = '14.5dp'
           self.root.add_widget(self.label03)
           with self.label03.canvas:
               Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
               Rectangle(pos=self.label03.pos, size=self.label03.size)
       elif text == "Normal":
           self.label03.text = ""
   ```

   if **name** == "**main**":
       LRefConfigAutomation().run()

[image]

Comment: Can you add your Error?

Comment: i have added the error image

Comment: Can you please also make a [minimal, reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then format your code as code?

Comment: actually i'm unable to do that one ,i'm getting lot of errors ,could you please help me

Comment: https://github.com/BollamReddy-Python-Vba/python/blob/master/TestData --- I have pasted my code in GitHub, Kindly look into it

Comment: Ok i will try your code. may take a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210930/discussion-between-just-learned-it-and-bollamreddy).

Answer (score 0):

In CreateLabel, you need to move the creation part outside of the if condition:
So this part

```
lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'NormalFolderName')
        self.label03 = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),
                                 halign="left", valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
        self.label03.bind(size=self.label03.setter('text_size'))
        self.label03.font_size = '14.5dp'
        self.root.add_widget(self.label03)
```

should be before `if text == "Official":`.
Otherwise, you get an error because you haven't created `self.label03`.
Complete CreateLabel:

```
def CreateLable(self, spinner, text):
        config = self.config
        lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'NormalFolderName')
        self.label03 = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),
                                 halign="left", valign="middle")
        self.label03.bind(size=self.label03.setter('text_size'))
        self.label03.font_size = '14.5dp'
        self.root.add_widget(self.label03)
        if text == "Official":            
            with self.label03.canvas:
                Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
                Rectangle(pos=self.label03.pos, size=self.label03.size)
        elif text == "Normal":
            self.label03.text = ""
```

---

There's another problem in CreateLabel:

```
self.label03 = Label(...)
```

Everytime you call CreateLabel, self.label03 is assigned a new Label, not the first one. So instead of hiding the first one you're creating a new one and hiding this. There are multiple ways to solve but here's one:

```
def build(self):
    ... # add these two lines to create the Label once
    self.CreateLabel()  
    root.add_widget(self.label03)
    # Use another function (UpdateLabel) to update the value
    self.requestsspinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)
    self.requestsspinner.bind(text=self.UpdateLable)
    ...

# Only called once to create the Label
def CreateLabel(self):
    self.label03 = Label(text="", pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),
                             halign="left", valign="middle")
    self.label03.bind(size=self.label03.setter('text_size'))
    self.label03.font_size = '14.5dp' 
    with self.label03.canvas:
        Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
        Rectangle(pos=self.label03.pos, size=self.label03.size)

# Changes the Label 
def UpdateLable(self, spinner, text):        
    if text == "Official":
        config = self.config
        self.label03.text =  config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'NormalFolderName')            
    elif text == "Normal":
        self.label03.text = ""
```

Comment: It is not working , could you give me any other solution if you have

Comment: Actually whenever i click on the spinner value normal label should hide